# Python runs the commented-out code

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

I have a problem that sometimes `docker-py` returns an error:

```
Permission denied.
```

I'm trying to fix it. I commented out the piece of code, and received the following picture.

```
File "/opt/dst/src/utils/runner.py", line 48, in run_code

\#if len(cli.containers(filters={'status': ['running', 'created']})) >= settings.DOCKER_CONTAINER_COUNT:
```

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/dst/src/core/tasks.py", line 12, in run
    return 'Solution not found'
  File "/opt/dst/src/utils/runner.py", line 48, in run_code
    #if len(cli.containers(filters={'status': ['running', 'created']})) >= settings.DOCKER_CONTAINER_COUNT:
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 85, in containers
    res = self._result(self._get(u, params=params), True)
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 132, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 487, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/dst/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 453, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

The runner.pyc file is updated.
What could be the problem?
Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english

UPDATE:

```
cli = Client('unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='1.19')
kill_client = Client('unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='1.19', timeout=0.5)
config = cli.create_host_config(**get_host_config(file_path))
#if len(cli.containers(filters={'status': ['running', 'created']})) >= settings.DOCKER_CONTAINER_COUNT:
#    return 'must retry', None
run_string = 'timeout {} python /tmp/script.py'.format(settings.DOCKER_EXECUTE_TIME)
container = cli.create_container('python:2', run_string, user=uid, host_config=config)
```

Comment: what happens if you delete the commented out code and run it, does it work fine then?

Comment: please provide code block with few lines of code around the one your commented out

Comment: from memory python 3 interprets comments `""" comment"""` like this, the single line comment is what you need `#comment` (have you saved it?), is your jf condition more than `80` characters ? try splitting it into 2 lines with ` \ ` and then comment both lines

Comment: _Add_ the lines of code **around** the block that's causing the error, otherwise we're all just going to sit here speculating and not be able to help you. Or just add your full code, please.

Answer (score 1):

Due to an error in the script, worked two instance celery and this error occurred during the operation instance, who has worked with the old code.